# Extract column of matrices from a 3D indexes

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I try to extract columns of matrices(in 2D) from a set of given indices(in 3D), without converting the 2D matrix into 3D so as to efficiently use memory (I'm dealing with very huge data), can I achieve this? I'll reuse the 2D matrix for each slice of the 3D matrix, but I just don't know how to do it. Example code:

```
A=rand(9,100); %The matrix that will be reused
B=randi([1 100],[1 100 30]); %the indices
Extracted=A(:,B); %this part I can't seem to solve it yet
```

Expected output of `Extracted` would be `9x100x30`. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution can be using inline function and `arrayfun`:

```
A=rand(9,100); %The matrix that will be reused
B=randi([1 100],[1 100 30]); %the indices
func = @(x) A(x);
Extracted = arrayfun(func, B);
```

Another solution is convert 3D matrix `B` to a vector.
Then using your method to retrieve `Extracted`:

```
A=rand(9,100); %The matrix that will be reused
B=randi([1 100],[1 100 30]); %the indices
idx = reshape(B,1,numel(B));
Extracted = A(idx);
```

Comment: Using the first method, the output of `Extracted` would be `1x100x30`, it missed the other 8 rows though.

Comment: @GregorIsack If `B`'s elements are linear index, so it does not happen.